# com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected status 201 for http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/new but was 404

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, wiremock

This is my Test Class:

```
public class CompanionDevicesRestServiceTest {

    public static ComDevicesRestService comDevicesRestService;
    public static IComDevices cdevicesService;
    public static ComDevices cdevicesRequest;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        cdevicesService = new StubComDevicesService();
        comDevicesRestService = new ComDevicesRestService(cdevicesService);
        cdevicesRequest = mock(ComDevices.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPostCdevices() throws JsonProcessingException{
        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/cdevices"))
                  .withHeader("Accept", WireMock.equalTo("application/json"))
                   .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody("Some content")));

    }
}
```

I am getting the following error :

> com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: Expected status 201 for http://localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/new but was 404
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.postJsonAssertOkAndReturnBody(HttpAdminClient.java:156)
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.HttpAdminClient.addStubMapping(HttpAdminClient.java:65)
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:138)
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.register(WireMock.java:134)
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.givenThat(WireMock.java:65)
>           at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.java:69)
>           at com.charter.cdevices.rest.CompanionDevicesRestServiceTest.testPostCdevices(CompanionDevicesRestServiceTest.java:33)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
>           at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

Answer (score 3):

For this example, I suppose the wiremock was started externally,right? So you should add the configure for with the host and the port:

```
configureFor("localhost", 8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the WireMock rule

```
@Rule
public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule();
```

and after that you could use it to create your stubs

```
wireMockRule.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/cdevices"))
              .withHeader("Accept", WireMock.equalTo("application/json"))
               .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                    .withStatus(200)
                    .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withBody("Some content")));
```

Answer (score 1):

ClassRule annotation can be also used:

```
public class CompanionDevicesRestServiceTest {

  public static ComDevicesRestService comDevicesRestService;
  public static IComDevices cdevicesService;
  public static ComDevices cdevicesRequest;


  @ClassRule
  public static WireMockClassRule wireMockRule = new WireMockClassRule(wireMockConfig()
    .containerThreads(20)
    .port(8080)
  );

  @BeforeClass
  public static void init(){
    cdevicesService = new StubComDevicesService();
    comDevicesRestService = new ComDevicesRestService(cdevicesService);
    cdevicesRequest = mock(ComDevices.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testPostCdevices() throws JsonProcessingException{
    wireMockRule.stubFor(WireMock.post(WireMock.urlEqualTo("/cdevices"))
      .withHeader("Accept", WireMock.equalTo("application/json"))
      .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
        .withStatus(200)
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .withBody("Some content")));

  }
}
```

and call stubFor method on the class rule object.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [WireMock documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/), we have three major approaches: JUnit 5.x, Junit4.x, and standalone.

My recommendation would be simple: double-check which approach is yours and proceed to the documented recommendation, but...

It never worked for me. In order to fix the issue discussed here, I did the following:

1. Added a @Rule to the very beginning of the test. I will share the entire class declaration down here, including the runner and a short SSL witchery to run this stuff with PowerMockRunner:

```js
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  
    @PowerMockIgnore("javax.net.ssl.*")  
    public class StartingOddsChangesProviderIntegrationTest {  
    
    @Rule public WireMockRule wireMockRule = new WireMockRule();  
    (...)
```

2. You **DO NOT** need to do instantiate a WireMockServer, neither need you to add a server.start()/stop() line now that the @Rule annotation is there.

Finally, the WireMock depedency entry in the corresponding pom.xml file is as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.27.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I've tried the wiremock-jre8 artifact as well, but I ended up having the same error, so I'm pushing ahead with the wiremock-standalone.